# Why am I getting a NullPointerException when I try to run my JFrame?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jframe, instance

I know this is really simple, but since I've instantiated the class, I can't understand why I'm getting this exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

at javax.swing.ImageIcon.(ImageIcon.java:181)

at GameFrame.(GameFrame.java:16)

at GameFrame.main(GameFrame.java:88)

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    //Mini games and main panel components
    private JPanel MainPanel;
    private JPanel gamePanel1, gamePanel2, gamePanel3, gamePanel4, gamePanel5, gamePanel6, gamePanel7, gamePanel8, gamePanel9;
    private JPanel[] gamePanels = {gamePanel1, gamePanel2, gamePanel3, gamePanel4, gamePanel5, gamePanel6, gamePanel7, gamePanel8, gamePanel9};
    private JButton[][] buttons;
    private int turn;

    //X and O images
    private JLabel X = new JLabel();
    private ImageIcon x = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/X.PNG"));   
    private JLabel O = new JLabel();
    private ImageIcon o = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/O.PNG"));


    //constructor       
    public GameFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        //gf.setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);

        setUpMainPanel();
        add(MainPanel);
    }

    public void setUpMainPanel() {
        //sets the layout
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GameFrame frame = new GameFrame();
    }
}
```

I've tried doing all the constructor things (e.g. setVisible(true)) in main() but I get the same error. Surprisingly, there's not a lot of easily findable info on this. Why is the imageIcon giving it a problem? Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: Where do you get the NPE?

Comment: The _easily findable info_ is in your error message. Post the complete stacktrace.

Comment: I'm guessing you don't need the leading "/" of your file name.

Comment: _Another issue:_ `setUpMainPanel` should be `private` (that is `final`). Because a child instance might not be entirely initialized when its overriden `setUpMainPanel` is called.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that the problem is in bad path to your images.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is that your application cannot find the pictures.

Can you add a

```
System.out.println(getClass().getResource("/Images/X.PNG"));
```

And show the results? I guess the result will print 'null'. If so, the location for the image is incorrect, for example, the leading slash can be wrong, or mind the casing of the file or path.

Comment: Good guess, the path must be case sensitive too.

Comment: I think you might be right. What should I lead with in terms of the local URL? Should it be "src/Images/X.PNG" or what?

Comment: Look in the produced .jar with 7Zip or WinZip. Likely not with "src". Being a zip-file, case-sensitive names are a must.

Comment: Where do I add the System.out.println statement? I can't add it in the static main method. Is there another way of determining the location of the image? And where should I put the images folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
   BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Images/X.PNG"));
   if(image != null)
       ImageIcon x = new ImageIcon(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   //X and O images
   private JLabel X = new JLabel();
   //try changing these around; EX:
   private ImageIcon x = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("X.PNG"));   
   private ImageIcon x = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Images/X.PNG"));   
   private JLabel O = new JLabel();
   private ImageIcon o = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("previousFolder/Images/O.PNG"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no image in this "/Images/X.PNG" location. Put an image "X.PNG" in /Images directory

Comment: I have one in there. I'm new to eclipse. Where should I place the images directory? I have my Java Project, the bin, .settings, and src folders.

Comment: try put your images to Project folder (same folder, where are bin, src and .settings). And in code use `...getResource("x.png")`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up placing

```
X = new JLabel();
x = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/X.PNG"));

O = new JLabel();
o = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Images/O.PNG"));
```

in the

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
```